# How would you handle filtering in an ECommerce website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i'm trying to practice and learn the mern stack by building an ECommerce website in order to use as many skills as possible together. I would like to ask how would you guys go about the filtering of products, for example if i have a cpus/processors page, i would like to filter them based on brand (amd, intel). What i've done till now that kinda works but isn't trully correct is this:

```
   const [cpus, setCpus] = useState([]); // here i save the cpus i get from the database
    const [defaultData, setDefaultData] = useState([]); //here i keep a copy of the original 

    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(cpuUrl);
        setCpus(data);
        setDefaultData(data);
      };
      fetchData();
    }, []);

    function filterProducts(event) {

    const currentState = [...cpus];
    let newState = currentState;

    if (event.target.checked === true && event.target.name === "AMD") {

      newState = currentState.filter((cpu) => cpu.subcategory.includes("AMD"));
      setCpus(newState);

    } else if (event.target.checked === true && event.target.name === "Intel") {

      newState = currentState.filter((cpu) =>
        cpu.subcategory.includes("Intel")
      );
      setCpus(newState);

    } else {

      setCpus(defaultData);
    }
  }
```

this is the filter component:

```
<Filters filterBrand1="AMD" filterBrand2="Intel" filterProducts={filterProducts} />
```

and this is the content of the filter component:

```
<div className="filter-contents">
    <div>
      <input
        name="AMD"
        type="checkbox"
        className="checkbox"
        onChange={props.filterProducts}
      ></input>
      <label className="filter-label">{props.filterBrand1}</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        name="Intel"
        type="checkbox"
        className="checkbox"
        onChange={props.filterProducts}
      ></input>
      <label className="filter-label">{props.filterBrand2}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So now for my question, would you guys create a different api endpoint for every brand ,like for amd get the amd cpus from the amd api endpoint and for intel likewise or would you do something similar to me with using the filter function and changing the state of the cpus everytime to display the correct data. What's the best approach to this and why if you could explain please.
Also feel free to point any coding mistakes ,i'd like to learn typing good code. Thanks in advance!